# How to integrate MailChimp in C#/.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp

I want to send email through MailChimp. How to do this in .Net?

Does any one have sample code?

Answer (score 16):

The example below will send a opt-in email:

First install the NuGet package: Install-Package mcapi.net

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string apiKey = "6ea5e2e61844608937376d514-us2";   // Replace it before
        const string listId = "y657cb2495";                      // Replace it before

        var options = new List.SubscribeOptions();
        options.DoubleOptIn = true;
        options.EmailType = List.EmailType.Html;
        options.SendWelcome = false;

        var mergeText = new List.Merges("email@provider.com", List.EmailType.Text)
                    {
                        {"FNAME", "John"},
                        {"LNAME", "Smith"}
                    };
        var merges = new List<List.Merges> { mergeText };

        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, false);
        var batchSubscribe = mcApi.ListBatchSubscribe(listId, merges, options);

        if (batchSubscribe.Errors.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Error:{0}", batchSubscribe.Errors[0].Message);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Success");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. By far the fastest and easiest way.

Comment: fiddler indicates this is sending to v1.3 of the api and with 3.0 now live the prior versions will not be supported after 2016. oh and it didnt appear to work anyway

Comment: see answer by @Pranav Singh way below

Answer (score 3):

Do Check out https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET by **Dan Esparza**
You can install the package by using **Package Manager Console**

```
Install-Package MailChimp.NET
```

**Code example**

```
MailChimpManager mc = new MailChimpManager("YourApiKeyHere-us2");
ListResult lists = mc.GetLists();
```

For **email sending** and stats, **Mailchimp** offers **Mandrill** by **Shawn Mclean** https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet

You can install Mandrill using

```
Install-Package Mandrill
```

**Code example**

```
MandrillApi api = new MandrillApi("xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");
UserInfo info = await api.UserInfo();
```

Comment: Dan Esparza now has a note on that project page to check out the v3 one by Brandon Seydel, (noted in Pranav's answer) since that's only for the v2.0 API which has been deprecated.