# Calling MailChimp API v3.0 with .Net

Tags: c#, http, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to access our MailChimp account via the new 3.0 REST API.  I've done the following:

```
using(var http = new HttpClient())
{
    var creds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:mailchimpapikey-us1"));
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", creds);
    string content = await http.GetStringAsync(@"https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists");
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get a 401 error with the following json details:

```
{"type":"http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/error-docs/401-api-key-invalid","title":"API Key Invalid","status":401,"detail":"Your API key may be invalid, or you've attempted to access the wrong datacenter.","instance":"a9fe4028-519e-41d6-9f77-d2caee4d4683"}
```

The datacenter I'm using in my URI (us1 in this example) matches the dc on my API key.  My API key works if I use the MailChimp SDK so I know my key isn't invalid.  Also, using Fiddler, I can see that the MailChimp SDK is calling the same dc as I'm doing in my URI.

Any Ideas as to why I am having trouble Authenticating?

**EDIT**
As noted in the question, I'm asking specifically about accessing the new 3.0 REST API.  I'm trying to do this directly as opposed to using a third party wrapper.

The new API is composed of http calls so it should be pretty straight forward.  I'm simply having trouble with the authentication piece.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate MailChimp in C#/.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802667/how-to-integrate-mailchimp-in-c-net)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I was able to finally chat with a **super** tech support person at MailChimp.

The MailChimp docs state the following

> The easiest way to authenticate is using HTTP Basic Auth. Enter any string
>   as the username and supply your API Key as the password.
>   Your HTTP library should have built-in support for basic authorization.

Their documentation is a bit misleading.  Typically the Auth header for Basic Auth would look like what I was sending:

> Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   where the row of x would represent the base64 encoded username:password.

However, talking with the support tech, the actual implementation they use is:

> Authorization: username keyid

No base64 encoding, no Basic keyword.  Username doesn't even have to be your username.

So, here is the working code:

```
using(var http = new HttpClient())
{
   http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", mailchimpapikey-us1);
   string content = await http.GetStringAsync(@"https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists");
   Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

**EDIT**
Note the comments.  TooMuchPete was correct in that the normal HTTP Basic Auth headers do work.  Apparently I was hitting some old code or something on the MailChimp side.

I'm leaving the post as a reference for anyone who is trying to call the new 3.0 API.

Comment: Incidentally, you can replace the word "Basic" with your username if you so desire in the AuthenticationHeaderValue constructor and things still work fine.

Comment: This is actually only partially correct -- the way support offered does work, but the API's primary method of authentication is HTTP Basic Auth. Here's some sample .NET code that does that in a less hacky way: https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/8102915

Comment: Hmm, your code looks almost identical to the non-working code I had originally posted.  Do you see any reason why yours would work and mine would not?

Comment: It looks like there might have been a bug that required the username to be 'apikey', but that was recently fixed. I'd give your original code another try and see if it works now.

Comment: Wow, you're right.  Today the "non-working" code runs just fine.  Yesterday that same code was failing all over the place.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: I tried your example, but I get errors that await can only be used within an async method. So, I started going backwards, making method after method async methods.. finally I came to a point which can not be passed, and I had to undo all that work. Do you have an example that isn't using async methods? We develop mission critical server events that can not run asynchronously.

Comment: When I test your code I get errors saying I need to make the containing scope async. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I think you could accomplish this by adding .Result to the end of the http call. (i.e.: `string content = http.GetStringAsync(@"...").Result;`)

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp Ecommerce

```
var mcorder = new Standup.Ecomm.MailChimpManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpApiKey"]);
var orders = new MailOrder();

orders.CampaignId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpCampaignId"];
orders.EmailId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpEmailId"];

orders.Id = orderNumber;
orders.StoreId = "abcde";
orders.StoreName = "E-Commerce Store";
orders.Total = Convert.ToDouble(orderTotal);
orders.Tax = Convert.ToDouble(tax);
orders.Items = new List<MailOrderItem>();
foreach (var orderItem in orderItemList)
{
    var item = new MailOrderItem();
    item.ProductId = orderItem.OrderNumber;
    item.ProductName = orderItem.Title;
    item.SKU = orderItem.Sku;
    item.CategoryId = 0;
    item.CategoryName = " ";
    item.Quantity = orderItem.Quantity;
    item.Cost = Convert.ToDouble(orderItem.ProductCost);
    orders.Items.Add(item);
}
mcorder.AddOrder(orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on a simple way up adding subscribers to a list using:

```
Dim mailchimp As New ZmailChimp
Dim ListId$ = "9b2e63f0b9"   'List Sage' List
Dim email$ = "samsmith20@anymail.com" '"sam19@postcodelite.com"
Dim fieldListOnAdd = "FNAME,Sam,LNAME,Smith,MTYPE,User,MID,631637"
Dim fieldListOnUpdate = "FNAME,Sam,LNAME,Smith,MID,631637"  'Don't change MTYPE
'Put on 'Sage One' and 'Sage 50' group
Dim groupList = "407da9f47d,05086211ba"

With mailchimp
     .API$ = "46cMailChimpAPIKeyd1de-us14" 'MailChimp API key
     .dataCenter$ = "us14"  'Last 4 letters of API key
     .password$ = "Password!"
     MsgBox(.addSubscriber(ListId$, email, fieldListOnAdd, fieldListOnUpdate, groupList))
End With
mailchimp = Nothing
```

see:http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1140339/Mail-Chimp-Add-Update-e-mail-to-List-and-Subscribe
this may save someone some time

Comment: did you tried https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net ? real world samples ?