# calling mailchimp api v3.0 with C#

Tags: c#, mailchimp, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to subscribe a client to a list, I have created a method to call mailchimp api but it is giving me bad request everytime I try, I tried calling a Get Method and it worked, I don't know what I am doing wrong I tried this one already [Calling MailChimp API v3.0 with .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360451/calling-mailchimp-api-v3-0-with-net)

this is my code so far

```
            try
            {
              JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
              var info = new Info() { email_address = "example@example.com", status = "subscribed" };

              var infoJson = serializer.Serialize(info);

              string url = @"https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/xxxxx/members";
              HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
              client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==");

              HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, infoJson).Result;
              if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
              {
                //something
              }
              else
              {
               //something else
              }


            return Ok();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
          } 

        public class Info
        {
            public  string email_address { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }
```

Thanks for you help in advance

Comment: What is the error message being returned from MailChimp? See [this section](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#errors) of the docs on dealing with errors.

Comment: The error I am getting is 400 bad Request, but no more data to clarify the problem

Comment: 400 Bad Request errors come with a lot more detail than that (see the doc link for an example). You'll want to figure out how to access the error response body/text to see what the error is.